# how if i want to save the edited file in different name instead replace the original file?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.docx') === TRUE) {

$xmlString = $zip->getFromName('word/document.xml');
$xmlString = str_replace('$FIRST_AND_LAST_NAME', 'John Doe', $xmlString);
$zip->addFromString('word/document.xml', $xmlString);

 echo 'ok';

$zip->close();
} else {
echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

I had using this code to replace some word in my docx file, but how if i want to save it in different file name instead of replace the original file. thanks.

Comment: Copy the file and work on a copy?

Comment: Thx, but i need automatic save in different name.

Comment: use `copy()` to copy the file, job done.